# OpenFDA Data: Labels with Boxed Warnings

Tags: openfda, api

I'd like to integrate boxed warning information from SPL with the [Pillbox Engine](https://github.com/HHS/pillbox-engine) so Pillbox users and developers can 1) know when a product has a boxed warning and 2) have access to the boxed warning text.

I haven't been able to determine the syntax to provide a set_id and receive the boxed_warning text, if it exists for that label.

To start, this call returns a label with a boxed_warning, but it appears to have a different set_id.

[https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=*exists*:boxed_warning+AND+set_id=3af2e694-6fea-46cf-b680-9ee0b0c83c88](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=_exists_:boxed_warning+AND+set_id=3af2e694-6fea-46cf-b680-9ee0b0c83c88)

```
 "spl_set_id": [
      "3fcabf90-357a-4a06-b680-9572dc28bcfe"
    ],
```

Answer (score 3):

You are pretty close, you just have a syntax error on the query that is getting interpreted as a search string: it should be `+AND+set_id:` not `+AND+set_id=`

Also, that particular set_id does not have a boxed_warning so it will not return anything.

The following query confirm the syntax and that the example is missing a boxed_warning.

[https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=*missing*:boxed_warning+AND+set_id:3af2e694-6fea-46cf-b680-9ee0b0c83c88](https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=_missing_:boxed_warning+AND+set_id:3af2e694-6fea-46cf-b680-9ee0b0c83c88)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, Hans.  I'm still confused by certain issues. Now that I've had mote time to think, I realize the query cannot include "missing" or exists" when referencing the boxed_warning, because the user will not know if it exists.  Also, I'm unsure why my query returns a label with a different set_id. Testing this I found this query also return a different label and says there are 52 matches. https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=set_id=d7c2edeb-ced4-4444-b519-d6b0299501c3

Comment: This is another setid= vs setid: issue. This is the query you want:

https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=set_id:d7c2edeb-ced4-4444-b519-d6b0299501c3

Comment: Let us know if this doesn't make sense!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Matt. This is great!  Is it possible to limit the results to a single, specified section, such as "boxed warning"?